# CodeIgniter Update database using ajax button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to update my data using an update button.

What I want to do is:

> When I click my data it turns into an input field where I can modify
>   the data and then when I click the update button the data should be
>   updated.

[image]

> I have the `update button` (the yellow button in picture) ready and the `data input field` is also ready
>   where I used `jQuery` found on net.

I don't know much about Ajax and jQuery. Database field names I want to update are `tname` and `time`

I need `Update Method` in `Controller`, `Update Method` in `Model` and `Codes` in `View`

Onclick turns into Input field codes:

```
<script>
 var switchToInput = function () {
                     var $input = $("<input>", {
                     val: $(this).text(),
                     type: "text"
                 });

            $input.addClass("loadNum");
            $(this).replaceWith($input);
            $input.on("blur", switchToSpan);
            $input.select();
      };

    var switchToSpan = function () {
                       var $span = $("<span>", {
                       text: $(this).val()
                       });

            $span.addClass("loadNum");
            $(this).replaceWith($span);
            $span.on("click", switchToInput);
    }
      $(".loadNum").on("click", switchToInput);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is something like this on your switchToInput function

```
$.ajax({
  url: "update.php", //This is your PHP code that will update the table using the model
  data: {tname: $("#idOfTheTnNameInput").val() ,time:$("#idOfTheTimeInput").val()}
}).done(function() {    //This function will be executed when the AJAX request end
  alert("table updated");
});
```

Comment: Ok I put these inside switchToInput function : 


`$.ajax ({
          url : "main/update_task",  // update method in controller
          data: {
            'tname' : $tname,
            'time' : $time
          }
        });`


But what should be those ID, Im confused. 

I viewed data using `foreach` loop `$row->tname` and `$row->time`.

Comment: Both input fields should have an id attribute in order to get the value of that input and send it to the AJAX request.
And to access to this values (with jQuery) we use $('#InputID').value()

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran I was taking about `data: {tname: $("#idOfTheTnNameInput").val() ,time:$("#idOfTheTimeInput").val()}`